# For $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$, is it true that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{n}^{n+1}f(x)dx=0$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, normed-spaces

This is from a prelim in analysis that I took yesterday. We have $f\in L^2(\mathbb R)$, and we are asked to prove or disprove the following:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_n^{n+1} f(x)dx=0
$$
I believe that the statement is true. I attempted a proof which I've tried to recreate below. Any criticisms or improved solutions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement is true.

We have: 
\begin{align*}
&\int_\mathbb R |f(x)|^2dx <\infty\\
\implies& \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_n^{n+1}|f(x)|^2dx<\infty\\
\implies& \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_n^{n+1}|f(x)|^2dx=0\\
\implies& \lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\int_n^{n+1}f(x)dx\right|^2=0&\text{(Cauchy-Schwarz)}\\
\implies& \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_n^{n+1}f(x)dx=0
\end{align*}

Comment: The sum in the second line looks fishy (the upper bound). Also, you should maybe justify why the first line implies the second one.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the upper bound, which was a typo. I'll add justification of the second line here: since the integrand is nonnegative, the integral over $[1,\infty)$ must be less than or equal to the integral over $\mathbb R$. And the integral over any interval is equal to the sum of integrals over countably many intervals that overlap on at most a set of measure zero. Probably I should justify that last statement too -- but I don't think the graders on my exam, at least, will require that.

Comment: The second line follows from Monotone Convergence.